# Set the axis range in a boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I'm working on this kaggle dataset on the EDA.

I´m working with some boxplot in pandas with this code:

```
coupon_list[["CATALOG_PRICE","VALIDEND_MONTH"]].boxplot(by='VALIDEND_MONTH')
```

The problem I'm havaing here is that the y axes has a large scale and it hard to read the plot. Is there any way to limit the sixze of this axis? something similar to ylim ?

[image]

EDIT:

The dataset have outliers, adding the argument:

```
showfliers=False
```

Seems to solve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's weird since by default the Y axis is autoscaled, see the example below. Maybe you have **some outliers** in your data. Could you share more code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed = 4

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
ax = df.boxplot()
```

[image: standard box plot]

Here is the same plot with outliers

```
# Generating some outliers
df.loc[0] = df.loc[0] * 10
ax = df.boxplot()
```

[image: outliers]

Could you try the `showfliers` option to plot the box without outliers? In this example the Y scale is back to [0-100].

```
ax = df.boxplot(showfliers=False)
```

> `showfliers` : bool, optional (`True`)
>   Show the outliers beyond the caps.
>   [matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html)